# StackOverFlowError when getting value of java list

Tags: java, stack-overflow

```
for(int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++)
{
    myEnum = MyEnum.values()[myList.get(i).getMyInteger()];
}
```

The above code gives me a StackOverflowError such as this:
java.util.AbstractList$SubAbstractList.get (AbstractList.java:292)

What are some possible causes for this?  I am unable to reproduce the issue, but have seen the stacktrace from crash reports.

The stacktrace is:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
       at java.util.AbstractList$SubAbstractList.get(AbstractList.java:292)
       at java.util.AbstractList$SubAbstractList.get(AbstractList.java:292)
       at java.util.AbstractList$SubAbstractList.get(AbstractList.java:292)
       at java.util.AbstractList$SubAbstractList.get(AbstractList.java:292)
       at java.util.AbstractList$SubAbstractList.get(AbstractList.java:292)
       at java.util.AbstractList$SubAbstractList.get(AbstractList.java:292)
       at java.util.AbstractList$SubAbstractList.get(AbstractList.java:292)
       at java.util.AbstractList$SubAbstractList.get(AbstractList.java:292)
       at java.util.AbstractList$SubAbstractList.get(AbstractList.java:292)
```

many calls of the same to the getter, originating from the line that sets the enum.

The list that is used here is a sublist.

Comment: Well where does this code occur? What does the stack trace look like?

Comment: You are apparently recursively calling the method so that's why you are getting the exception. Just break the recursion.

Comment: You can better show your full code.

Comment: Is this code snippet part of the static function `values()` of the class MyEnum?

Comment: What is the Java version you are using? AbstractList.java doesn't have code in line 292 in 1.6, 1.7 and 1.8.

Comment: Laune, I am using Android API 19 version of AbstractList

Comment: Jon Skeet, the error occurs on the line that sets the enum.  
Nessuno, values() is a built-in method that returns an an array.
There is no recursion that I can find, and I cannot reproduce the issue, which is why I am so confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was due to my misunderstanding of AbstractList.SubAbstractList (subList).  A subList returns a view of the list, not a new list.  I was performing this operation on different subLists obtained from the same full list.

Answer (score 0):

A stackoverflow occurs when you have a programm that recurses too deeply. To quote the [official Oracle docs](http://public%20class%20StackOverflowError%20extends%20VirtualMachineError):

> Thrown when a stack overflow occurs because an application recurses too deeply.

Since your code snippet is very short it's pretty much impossible to say where that error originates from.

Comment: Aw, come on. MyEnum.values is added by the Java compiler and returns an array containing all Enum values as they are written in the enum definition.

Comment: Damn it you're right. I rarely use enums in Java. Now I'm embarassed.

Comment: And quickly erase that "infinite loop". - Best to remove this non-answer entirely.

Comment: I agree that my answer was extremely faulty (I tried to reproduce a stackoverflow via an inifinite loop, which I could not. It is possible to produce an outofmemoryerror, though). I am unsure if the question in its current form can be answered in a satisfiable fashion.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest increasing the java heap size:

-Xms specifies the initial Java heap size and 
-Xmx the maximum Java heap size.

To set the minimum at 64Mb and the maximum at 256Mb

```
java -Xms64m -Xmx256m ...
```

try this and if it doesn't work rewrite your code to avoid recursions...

Comment: I'm trying to understand where the recursion is, as I do not see how it is possible.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the issue on my device, the stacktrace is from an error report.  I don't think the heap size will effect it because it appears to be calling the getter infinitely.  It'll probably fill up the heap no matter what the size.